# How to detect duplicates in Arraylist in java and append another variable from the same list to those duplicates

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I have an ArrayList containing fields like FirstName,LastName,Employee ID,Employee Job etc., When used to display the list, if at all an employee has the same first and Last names, his name(first+Last Name) should be appended with the employee ID and Job seperated by hyphen.

Iam able to detect the duplicates using Hash Set using Add Operation of Set. But on appending ID , it is being done for only one of the duplicates.

I should be able to differentiate Employees with same names based on appended ID and job.

Thanks :-)

Here is my Code:

```
List<AgentInfoVO>agentQueuesInfo = new ArrayList<AgentInfoVO>();

List<AgentInfo>agentQueues = null;    
Set<AgentInfo>uniqueSet = null;
StringBuffer lastName = null;

 if(agentQueuesInfo != null){
    agentQueues = new ArrayList<AgentInfo>();
    uniqueSet = new HashSet<AgentInfo>();
    forEach(AgentInfoVO agentInfoVO : agentQueuesInfo){
     AgentInfo agentInfo = new AgentInfo();
     agentInfo.setFirstName(agentInfoVO.getFirstName());
     agentInfo.setLastName(agentInfoVO.getLastName());

        // to check if duplicate names exist and append ID and Job to duplicates
        if(!uniqueSet.add(agentInfo)){
            lastName = agentInfoVO.getLastName();
            if(agentInfoVO.getAgentEmpID() != null){
             lastName = lastName.append("-" +agentInfoVO.getAgentEmpID());
            }
            if(agentInfoVO.etEmpJob() != null){
             lastName = lastName.append("-" +agentInfoVO.etEmpJob());
            }
            agentInfo.setLastName(lastName.toString());
        } 

     agentInfo.setAgentEmpID(agentInfoVO.getAgentEmpID());
     agentInfo.setEmpJob(agentInfoVO.etEmpJob());
     agentQueues.add(agentInfo);
    }
 }
```

Comment: where is your efforts in code? Add your code in your question.

Comment: You have an ArrayList of Employee objects which have those fields - firstName, lastName and others.. is that right ?

Comment: Pls add code as to what you have tried till now

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i dont have a computer close to me, so i cant give you code, but can share my ideas.

Detecting duplicates using set add method will only see the second entry as duplicate, thats why you will miss the first one.

If you can be able to modify AgentInfoVO, and firstName and LastName should uniquely identify AgentInfoVO.
A better way can be to overwrite the hash and equals method using using both fields.
And use this method to detect more than one occurrence and do your appends.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection, java.lang.Object).

something like:

```
Set<AgentInfoVO> duplicateAgentInfoVOs = new HashSet<AgentInfoVO>();
for(AgentInfoVO agentInfoVO : agentQueuesInfo) {
    if(Collections.frequency(agentQueuesInfo, agentInfoVO) >  1) {
       duplicateAgentInfoVOs.add(agentInfoVO);
    }
}

for(AgentInfoVO agentInfoVO : agentQueuesInfo) {
     if(duplicateAgentInfoVOs.contains(agentInfoVO)) {
         //you can do your appends to agentInfoVO 
     }
}
```